# Firemonkey, multiview current state

Tags: firemonkey

I am new to firemonkey and have an issue.  When i use the multiview.mode set to PlatformBehaviour and I am on my pc the display is a navigationPane with a collapsed width of 62.  This is so that some image icons are always displayed along the left hand side.  image on Imgur - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd4US.jpg

The issue is that the detail view (tab control) is aligned to the client and subsequently is starts behind the navigation pane (ie aligned to the left hand side of the screen when maximised).  When using multiview and panel option instead it is adjusted correctly to the edge of the multiview panel, but not when using navigation pane.

What i would like to do is determine the state of the multiview in the from.show and set a left margin on the detail view(tab control) to 63 so that is starts at the edge of the multiview navigation pane.

I have tried several of the options but cannot seem to get it to detect which mode it is in.  So, can anyone help with the specific line of code I need to detect which option is being displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out if anyone is interested.

Instead of trying to adjust it at runtime you can set the multiview.TargetControl inside the object inspector to whatever is in the detailview.  In my case it was the TabControl.  This then pushes it to the edge of the multiview panel.